# C - How to add multiple flags

Tags: c, flags, recv

Is this the right way to add multiple flags into a function?

```
recv(sfd, &buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_ERRQUEUE);
```

I don't get an error message in my `buf`. 
`recv()` does not block. 
I get errno: 11, which says "try again".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of FLAG in socket send and recv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430564/meaning-of-flag-in-socket-send-and-recv)

Comment: What does `recv` *return*? Please also try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: recv returns -1 and buf is empty. connect returned 0.

Comment: "[C]onnect returned 0" is odd on just about any system. The only place that would happen is for Windows systems (unless you're on a POSIX system and close the standard input/output/error).

Comment: "Man connect" says it returns 0 on success. I'm on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have added flags to the last parameter to `recv()` is fine. It seems you do not understand what the `MSG_DONTWAIT` will do.

The `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag will cause the `recv()` call to be performed as a non-blocking operation. That means it will return `-1` with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if there is no data to be returned.

> **`MSG_DONTWAIT`** (since Linux 2.2)
>
> - Enables nonblocking operation; if the operation would block,
>               the call fails with the error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.  This
>               provides similar behavior to setting the `O_NONBLOCK` flag (via
>               the `fcntl`(2) `F_SETFL` operation), but differs in that
>               `MSG_DONTWAIT` is a per-call option ...
>
> <sub>[man 2 recv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html)</sub>

If you want `recv()` to block until there is data returned, remove the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag, and make sure your socket is does not set `O_NONBLOCK`.